# Having both single and double quotes in a string

Tags: r

I am trying to create a vector of strings that look like: '"word"' '"Lebron James"' (it may be hard to see but that is a single quote followed by a double quote) but I can't figure out how to make that work for a string so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: which programming language are you using? In Java you quote single quotes by `\'` and double quotes by `\"`.

Comment: `x = '\'"word"\' \'"Lebron James"\''   ; cat(x)`

Comment: @andy I am using R

Comment: @JayLyons sorry, didn't recognize **r** as a programming language :-))

Comment: @G5W cat(x) is outputting strings in the correct format but I need to save them to a variable in that format so I can use it at a later point

Comment: @JayLyons  It _is_ stored in the correct format - in x.